# Android Tab Layout inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have a main Activity with a navigation drawer and I'm trying to realize a layout like Play Music App with tabs.

The MainActivity has a FrameLayout like a container:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and I want to put inside the @+id/container a Fragment with Tabs.

How's the best way to do this?

I thought I can create a MyFragment which extends Fragment and implements TabListener.
The associated layout could be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

But then how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following the following steps:

- First, create your activity and extend FragmentActivity and implement TabListener
- Secondly, create your TabsPagerAdapter
- Thirdly, create your fragment (or fragments if more than one is needed).
- You can then set the adapter in your activity after requesting navigation mode to tabs.

**Code Sample**

```
public class SampleActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.gd_pager);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        String [] tabs = new String[]{"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3", "Tab3"};

        for(String tab : tabs)
        {

           actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(tab)
                .setTabListener(this));
        }

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
       {
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

         viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
         {

             @Override
             public void onPageSelected(int position)
             {
                 actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
             }

             @Override
             public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
             {
             }

             @Override
             public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
             {
             }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I wouldn't change the Activity, I Would implements this in a Fragment contained in the MainActivity. Like in Google Paly Music, My Library. I don't think that's a different activity, do you?

Comment: I just updated the code; and sure, you can do the same in your fragment

Comment: The step I would avoid is the first: how can I use a Fragment instead a FragmentActivity ?

Comment: The reason why I am using FragmentActivity is because my pager loads fragments when a user swipes. That is the easiest - and good way to create swipe views with tabs (action bar). You decide; if there is a serious reason why you don't want to use an activity (FragmentActivity), think of an alternative.

Comment: You can also do this with a pager if you use the Fragment's fragment manager by calling [getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) when creating the adapter and second level pager.