# Fragment Tabs inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have in my Main Activity an Action bar navigation using tabs using Fragments (with Material Design), as below which works well, but now I wish to have Tab navigation within my Fragments...

```
// Add Fragments to Tabs in Main Activity
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FeedsFragment(), "Latest Updates");
    adapter.addFragment(new ClubTeamsFragment(), "Club Teams");
    adapter.addFragment(new FixturesFragment(), "Fixtures");
    adapter.addFragment(new ResultsFragment(), "Results");
    adapter.addFragment(new ClubFieldsFragment(), "Club Fields");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that TabHost is now deprecated.

I wish to achieve the attached image. The blue tabs are at the Main Activity level and the gray date tabs are in the selected fragment view.

[image]

I have read a few post about using Tab Host or Fragment Activity, or do I use Activity that is extended to Fragment?

Comment: Answer seems to work in the interim ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/27918056/1423608

Comment: can you please share your example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656303/1423608

Comment: https://github.com/sanjeevkumar2017/Tab-Inside-Fragment

Answer (score 74, accepted):

See below answer that I achieved with using fragment tabs inside fragment tabs that are in my MainActivity

Inside my fragment using **getChildFragmentManager()**

```
public class FixturesTabs extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fixtures_new_tabs,container, false);
    // Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.result_tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    return view;

}


// Add Fragments to Tabs
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {


    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TodaysFixturesFragment(), "Today");
    adapter.addFragment(new WeekFixturesFragment(), "Week");
    adapter.addFragment(new MonthFixturesFragment(), "Month");
    adapter.addFragment(new AllFixturesFragment(), "Month");
    adapter.addFragment(new MyTeamsFixturesFragment(), "My Teams");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);



}

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}



}
```

And my XML named "fixtures_new_tabs.xml" to match the inflated layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/medium_grey"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps or points others in the direction for their solution..

P.S. If you get a white screen after implementing this, you might have added the same parent fragment to it's child fragment.

Comment: So where should OnFragmentInteractionListener go? in the parent activity or in the fragment?

Comment: I know it's late but for future viewers : @SankaDarshana it is implemented by the parent activity

Comment: Never too late mate

Comment: @BENN1TH this is more or less similar to what i am looking for, only that i have dynamic tabs within the activity i wish to convert to a fragment , do you happen to have an idea how to fix my issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910317/how-do-i-convert-my-activity-containing-tabs-and-viewpager-into-fragment-contain

Comment: 404 on that link @Angela Heely

Comment: @BENN1TH I deleted that recently, just found an answer. Thanks for looking at it though, I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed a few things in Han and BENN1TH solution because the tab did not align properly, i added only two fragment. (they added five fragments). 
I hope this helps.

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: You mean: app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"