# Image Swipe Using View Pager inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am trying to create a swiping images inside fragment. I had created tabbed activity using view pager and this is working fine. In one of the tab I am trying to create Image swipe.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_fragment1, container, false);
    ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.collection1_viewPager);

    ImageSwipeAdapter imageSwipeAdapter= new ImageSwipeAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(imageSwipeAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

After deploying this the app stops working.

In some internet content it was mention to use

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

but it was also not working. What is the issue with the code?

Adapter code for Image Swipe

```
public class ImageSwipeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public ImageSwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment f= new ImageSwipe();
    Bundle args= new Bundle();
    args.putInt("count", position + 1);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

}

Fragment XML-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:id="@+id/collection1_viewPager">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="203dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: I think problem is with interrupt `ViewPager` accessibility with `ImageSwipeAdapter`.

Comment: Can you explain me what it is?

Comment: When you swipe in ImageSwiper application cannot catch whether it is for ViewPager or ImageSwiper and application crash.

Comment: after deploying my app doesnt even starts

Comment: Have you try with `getChildFragmentManager()` ?

Comment: yes I tried with it. but same result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413150/fragment-tabs-inside-fragment --I followed this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152116/discussion-between-nitin-patel-and-shubham-agarwal-bhewanewala).