# An example of how to create tabs within a bottom nav fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-bottomnav

I am trying to create tabs within a fragment. I have a 3 fragments
for example in this fragment named "fragment_home.xml", I want to add 2 tabs to it

here is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the java class with ViewModel for the fragment :
"HomeFragment.java" :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

"HomeViewModel.java" :

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is home fragment");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `viewpager`.

Comment: How ? can you give me an example, please ?

Comment: Please read this https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FixturesTabs extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fixtures_new_tabs,container, false);
// Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
setupViewPager(viewPager);
// Set Tabs inside Toolbar
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.result_tabs);
tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


return view;

}


// Add Fragments to Tabs
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {


Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new TodaysFixturesFragment(), "Today");
adapter.addFragment(new WeekFixturesFragment(), "Week");
adapter.addFragment(new MonthFixturesFragment(), "Month");
adapter.addFragment(new AllFixturesFragment(), "Month");
adapter.addFragment(new MyTeamsFixturesFragment(), "My Teams");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);



}

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
}



}
```

XML named "fixtures_new_tabs.xml" to match the inflated layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/medium_grey"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[you can read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413150/fragment-tabs-inside-fragment)